# Reflection.MethodInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, system.reflection

I'm trying to invoke a method by name - passed in as a string in an aspx code-behind class, like this:

```
private void callMethod( string method ) {
    object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance( this.GetType(), null );
    MethodInfo methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod( method );
    methodInfo.Invoke( classInstance, null );
}
```

But the method is in an inherited class and this code can't find the method. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Can you show your method and class ?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `BindingFlags` to your `GetMethod()` call.

For instance, assuming the method you want is public and not static:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod( method, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public );
```

Here you will find more information about `BindingFlags` and its possible values:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx

This is from the documentation:

> **Note**
>
> You must specify Instance or Static along with Public or NonPublic or no members will be returned.

Another way is to query the methods:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == method);
```

All this is assuming the methods you are finding are parameterless. If they have parameters, well, you'll need to add that information to the `GetMethod()` or `GetMethods()` method. Here is some documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx

Finally, it seems a little bit weird to create a new instance of the page class in that scenario. Maybe you actually want to execute the method to the current instance of the page instead a new one, in which case your code should look more like:

```
private void callMethod( string method ) {
    MethodInfo methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod( method );
    methodInfo.Invoke( this, null );
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but when using the `Type.GetMethod(string)` overload, it uses `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public` by default, so this is probably not the problem.

Comment: Maybe the method he is trying to find is private

Comment: thanks very much, the problem was that the method was with protected.

Comment: You solve it making it public or adding the correct `BindingFlags`?